# Starting a social pool club at work

Tags: pool, snooker

I work for a large company with a good social focus. I'm thinking of starting a weekly pool club for the interested. I've found a decent venue where we can go to have an informal get together, but wondering how it should be organized.

At least to start with, I have no idea how many people will turn up, or their levels of ability. I want it to be as inclusive as possible, so the social aspect is more important than the competition.

Does anyone have any experience or tips for running or attending such a club? Should we all just get down there and play it by ear, or is there some format I should consider?

Answer (score 1):

To find out how many people are interested, you need to ask. Use whatever method used in your workplace for informal communication amongst employees to make a simple poll. There are two things you want to know: how often they want to play and skill estimate (keep this simple, beginner-intermediate-experienced is enough of a scale).

Then set a date and book enough tables, consulting with appropriate people at work if you expect the company to pay for this.

If you want this to be social and fun, explore team variants of the game. More people at one table is more socializing and also it is easier to accomodate a player who is a lot stronger or weaker than others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encourage as many as possible, you may want to look at local pool leagues. As an example, I live in Basingstoke, UK and I compete in club tournaments within the [Basingstoke and District Club Pool League](https://bdcpl.leaguerepublic.com/l/league/893177303.html).

Teams can be as informal or formal as you like and entering your club into local pool leagues will increase knowledge of your club as players from other clubs will come to compete in league tournaments.

Check that you will be eligible before entering your club because there are leagues for bars and pubs which don’t include pool and snooker clubs.